# Is the regular expression syntax in asp.net and javascript identical?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

My question is as in the title. If two syntaxes are different then how to convert an regex in asp.net to javascript.

Really appreciated for anyone's answer.

**Edit**: I have the Regex to test email address like this:

```
"((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))"
```

It works fine in .net. But when I emulate the regex and use in javascript:

```
new RegeExp(regex).test(email);
```

It throws an syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression
```

So how can I use that terible regex in javascript?

Comment: If you use a string to construct a regex in JavaScript, you need to double the backslashes, for instance. There are also some other syntactical changes. See my edited answer for a converted regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from syntax differences, there are a lot of things that .NET has and JavaScript doesn't:

- lookbehind assertions
- support for Unicode properties (which also affects shorthand character classes like `\w`, word boundaries like `\b` etc.)
- recursive regexes
- forward references
- atomic grouping
- conditionals
- POSIX character classes
- named capturing groups
- a DOTALL option
- multiline regexes
- many other small details [as seen here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

So if your .NET regex uses any of those features, they need to be reworked substantially or (in the case of lookbehind and recursion) cannot be translated to JavaScript.

**Edit:**

In the case of your regex, it seems that mainly syntax changes are necessary (a task that I use [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) for). The resulting regex is this:

```
var myregexp = /((([a-z]|\d|[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))/;
```

I have no idea what this monster is supposed to be doing, so you need to test if it matches everything the way you expect it.

Comment: Really thankful for your discover:). It works as I expect. The regex looks very verbose, but at the moment I need to use it. And now I have known a strong tool to work with regex. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

They are different. To test how it would run in JavaScript you can do something like:

```
Regex.IsMatch("input", "regex", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
```

in .NET that will make it pretty much equivalent. If you can, run some code through it. That will help you to determine if they are working the same.

For writing and testing in JavaScript's RegEx implementation I highly recommend http://regexpal.com/ It runs 100% in browser and even highlights in real time for you.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses XRegExp and .NET uses Microsofts.  They are different.

XRegExp seems to have fewer features.

Wikipedia has a comparison chart http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: No. `XRegExp` is a third-party extension by Steve Levithan to JavaScript's native regex engine. It's not part of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are almost the same, but the syntax for usage can differ in different programming languages.

[RegExBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is a good tool to write RegEx and get the usage in most of the popular programming languages.

Comment: I would argue that JavaScript's native regexes are *vastly* inferior to .NET's regexes. They are not in the same ballpark, well, not even in the same league.

Comment: I dont want to argue buddy. I meant "almost same"